# Morrowind window glitching?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

I just got Morrowind (from the Anthology pack, if that makes a difference) and it's glitching on me. The window shows up but tabs on my taskbar (especially the Morrowind tab) flash really fast on my screen and I'm not able to click on anything in the game's window (it's fullscreen, but it's still a window). I haven't modded anything, and it's  on the highest settings (it only has fullscreen, windowed, and shading options anyway). I'm using a i5 4670k, 16gb 1600 DDR3 RAM, and a Radeon HD 7970 GHz edition graphics card so system requirements are completely out of the question. I also have the latest drivers (last time I checked about was about a week ago). What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried compatibility mode?

Comment: I didn't even realise morrowind had requirements, that is, I was running it a decade ago plus on a gutless computer